# The share link dialog box appears partly off a small screen

Tags: bug, design, responsive-design, mobile-chrome

While using the **Chrome** browser on my **iPhone SE**, I clicked "share" to get a link to a post.

> [image: share edit flag]

I noticed the **share dialog box appeared halfway off the screen.**

> [image: share dialog off the screen]

Then I repro'd this behavior on another post on my laptop using Chrome and reducing the screen width.

> [image: Share dialog off the screen repro]

Comment: Looks like the box is designed to appear flexibly so that it doesn't overlap any of the links (this is actually really nice). The more links there are, the further to the right it goes... or [down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnqsM.png). I think we can reconsider where it appears such that it avoids appearing over the links but also stays on the screen... that said, in some screen widths, it may be too wide even if it were pushed all the way to the left.

Comment: @Catija Now at least I understand *why* the dialog box appears so far right. To fix it, the box could be smaller on smaller screens, or appear below the links, or whatever works. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that if it appears inline with the far left of the links rather than popping up to the right of them, that may fix it for most screens, with something pushing it further left if the screen is even narrower.